# React bind and keep access to event object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

On Facebook's React tips page [Communicate Between Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) they show an example using javascript's bind() to pass arguments to the parent's handleClick() method.

This works well, except using bind the first argument of an event handler is no longer the event that was triggered.  I'd still like access to the event so what are my options in this regard?

Comment: `onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, i)}`

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfect.  I now can prevent default on the event as well as have access to e.target :)  Since this is a comment I can't mark it as the answer however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just specify it as

```
onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, i)}
```

That way you create a new anonymous function that both passes the original event and your custom data.

Comment: without ES6 how to write that ?
function(e) { 
return this.handleClick(e,i);
}
?

Comment: @FrançoisRichard nope, you need to capture `this` somewhere outside this anonymous function like `var that = this;` and then use `that` inside

Comment: so function(e) { var self = this; return self.handleClick(e,i); } would work right ?

Comment: @FrançoisRichard outside the function. In the function you have `this` already overwritten with something else.

Comment: hmm yes true, so how to do that without ES6 ? I thout somefctn => was a way to write function(somefctn) {}

Comment: @FrançoisRichard without ES6 you need to capture a reference to `this` **outisde** the anonymous function. "was a way to write function" --- that's right, but it's not 100% semantically identical and has its own special behaviours.

Comment: Digging in ES6 I just read " Unlike functions, arrows share the same lexical this as their surrounding code." That's why it's working without bothering of getting the right scope I guess